# php cant use simplexml_load_file with special characters

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to receive xml in my php project using the simplexml_load_file() method.

But when the xml that i get from the url contains special characters, i get the error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://www....: parser error : Entity 'Eacute' not defined
```

One of the xml tags contains the text:

```
&Eacute;monda SL 5
```

Is there any way how i can avoid this error? I do not have access to these xml files, so i cannot place the text between CDATA tags.

Comment: Can you show it in context of the surrounding tags, please

Comment: https://c0146023c3474ddd9c54350d60f05c97.hst.fietsenwijk.nl/fietsen/xml/detail/?b=D7E8335CC44B45A7BC498AEBFFED34C8 This link is the xml i want to read. BicycleModel has the text where it crashes. @ADyson

Comment: `i cannot place the text between CDATA tags.`...it seems to be in a CDATA tag alrready?

Comment: @ADyson Some tags have CDATA already, but <bicycleModel> doesn't, and thats where it crashes.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is not "special characters", the problem is invalid XML. That file does not pass any XML validator I've tried. This is what happens when providers plug XML together by concatenating strings instead of using XML libraries. 

Comment: `&Eacute;` is a named entity that is only available in (X)HTML, not in XML.. So an XML parser will not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the ampersands with a slug before simplexml processing but then you need to un-slug the content before using it.

```
$xmlObj = readXml($xml);
echo decodeXml($xmlObj->bicycleModel);

function readXML($xmlStr){
    $xmlStr = str_replace("&", "{{entity}}", $xmlStr);
    return simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
}

function decodeXml($xmlNode){
    $str = str_replace("{{entity}}", "&", (string) $xmlNode);
    $str = html_entity_decode($str);
    return $str;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WBUGt#v8.2.4